# Authentication in asp.net redirect to wrong page showing following error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Authentication in asp.net redirect to wrong page showing following error

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

In web.config file I am using following code

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx">
      <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
        <user name="Waqas" password="abc"/>
        <user name="Hamza" password="123"/>
     </credentials>

    </forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
   <deny users ="?" />

</authorization>
```

So when I run the `Login.aspx` page above message is shown.

And redirected to following Url

localhost:2006/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fLogin.aspx

Comment: What URL are you redirected to?

Comment: http://localhost:2006/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fLogin.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using full paths for your login.aspx page. So:

> "~/Account/Login.aspx"